# Hold a ImageView exactly in place XML

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I have following problem, I want to add a ImageView (the Google Play button) to my dialog which stays in place, no matter which device the app is running on.

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

This is what it looks like on some devices:

[image]

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goProDialogImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/goldversiondialog"/>



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/googleplaybutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/goProDialogImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/goProDialogImage"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:maxHeight="250dp"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gpbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I tell the app to never put the Image above the golden veil?

Comment: In which folder did you place goldversiondialog.png?

Comment: @Michiel drawable

Comment: Does it work like intended if you put it in fi. `drawable-hdpi` folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/googleplaybutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have removed some of your properties, the key point is that you need to use `weightSum` in `LinearLayout` and apply `weight` to your `ImageView`(I have given 0.5, you can change according to your need). Also, do not set `android:scaleType` to `fitXY`, keep the aspect ratio so the height will change according to the width.